# Python：How to make windows binary installation exe for my package?

Tags: python-3.x

I found a lot compiled exe installation file for many packages here:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Any body know how can I create the installation exe like this in python3?

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Create your setup.py](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/) that uses distutils or setuptools, and use the `bdist_wininst` verb. It's all [in the manual](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/builtdist.html#creating-windows-installers).

```
python setup.py bdist_wininst
```